# Qt How can I get a signal from int when the value changes?

Tags: c++, qt, signals

So lets say I a QDialog class like this

```
class DiagExample : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    DiagExample(QWidget *parent);

private:
    int myIntValue = 0;

    QPushButton *AddToValue;
    QPushButton *MinusToValue;
    QLabel *counter;

};
```

And the implementation looks like this

```
DiagExample::DiagExample(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    setWindowTitle("Example Diag");

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
   
    AddToValue = new QPushButton(tr("Add"));
    MinusToValue = new QPushButton(tr("Minus"));
    counter = new QLabel;

    connect(AddToValue, &QPushButton::released, [=](){myIntValue++;});
    connect(MinusToValue, &QPushButton::released, [=](){myIntValue--;});

    layout->addWidget(AddToValue);
    layout->addWidget(MinusToValue);
    layout->addWidget(counter);

    // below is what I want to achieve but have no idea how
    // essentially when value of the int is changed, text of
    // counter (QLabel) will be set to the new value

    connect(myIntValue, ???, [=](int newValue){ 
        counter->setText(QString::number(newValue);});
}
```

I know that I could go straight from QPushButton::released -> setText on the QLabel, but my code will eventually have many inputs feeding into the counter, so from a point of readability and simplicity, I would rather have this sort of paradigm --- INPUT_WIDGET -> myIntValue -> setText(NEW VALUE OF myIntValue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard way of doing such things in Qt:

```cpp
class DiagExample : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(intValue READ intValue NOTIFY onIntValueChange)

public:
    DiagExample(QWidget *parent);

    int intValue() const;

signals:
    void onIntValueChange(int);

private:
    int myIntValue = 0;

    QPushButton *AddToValue;
    QPushButton *MinusToValue;
    QLabel *counter;
};
```

Now in cpp:

```cpp
DiagExample::DiagExample(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    setWindowTitle("Example Diag");

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
   
    AddToValue = new QPushButton(tr("Add"));
    MinusToValue = new QPushButton(tr("Minus"));
    counter = new QLabel;

    connect(AddToValue, &QPushButton::released, [=](){
       myIntValue++;
       emit onIntValueChange(myIntValue);
    });
    connect(MinusToValue, &QPushButton::released, [=](){
       myIntValue--;
       emit onIntValueChange(myIntValue);
    });

    layout->addWidget(AddToValue);
    layout->addWidget(MinusToValue);
    layout->addWidget(counter);

    // below is what I want to achieve but have no idea how
    // essentially when value of the int is changed, text of
    // counter (QLabel) will be set to the new value

    connect(this, &DiagExample::onIntValueChange, [=](int newValue){ 
        counter->setText(QString::number(newValue);});
}

int DiagExample::intValue() const {
    return myIntValue;
}
```

Note only `QObject` can emit signals!

Comment: public signals? Interesting (:

Comment: why it is strange? If you what to connect (from outside of class) using `&DiagExample::onIntValueChange` it must be public.

Comment: `Signals are public access functions and can be emitted from anywhere, but we recommend to only emit them from the class that defines the signal and its subclasses.` [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Comment: I've misunderstood your comment, I've forgot that `signals` is a macro representing `public`(I do not use Qt for +5 years).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define it yourself, something like that could work:

```
class DiagExample : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    DiagExample(QWidget *parent);

private:
    int myIntValue = 0;

    QPushButton *AddToValue;
    QPushButton *MinusToValue;
    QLabel *counter;

private slots:
    void onPlusOne();
    void onMinusOne();

signals:
    void intValueChanged(const QString& newVal);
};
```

and then in you cpp file:

```
DiagExample::DiagExample(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    setWindowTitle("Example Diag");

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
   
    AddToValue = new QPushButton(tr("Add"));
    MinusToValue = new QPushButton(tr("Minus"));
    counter = new QLabel;

    connect(AddToValue, &QPushButton::released, &DiagExample::onPlusOne);
    connect(MinusToValue, &QPushButton::released, &DiagExample::onMinusOne);
    connect(this, &DiagExample::intValueChanged, counter, &QLabel::setText);

    layout->addWidget(AddToValue);
    layout->addWidget(MinusToValue);
    layout->addWidget(counter);

    // below is what I want to achieve but have no idea how
    // essentially when value of the int is changed, text of
    // counter (QLabel) will be set to the new value

    connect(myIntValue, ???, [=](int newValue){ 
        counter->setText(QString::number(newValue);});
}

void DiagExample::onPlusOne()
{
    myIntValue++;
    emit intValueChanged(QString::number(myIntValue));
}

void DiagExample::onMinusOne()
{
    myIntValue--;
    emit intValueChanged(QString::number(myIntValue));
}
```